# Finding the largest integer in a string of digits

Tags: c#, user-input

I have a string of digits that I have received as user input. How can I determine the maximum number entered?

For example, if the user entered `1236985`, the maximum number is `9`.

Comment: The community here does everything they can to help, but you have to atleast show some effort and post what you have tried so far

Comment: he doesn't have to really, people are seeminly bursting at the chance of answering

Comment: @Weyland It appears you are correct

Comment: Why are people upvoting this question?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard So that more people will ask great questions like this!

Comment: @Donut [You should know better than adding "Thanks in advance" to questions.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) And OP didn't mention LINQ, the fact that all the answers use it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to do it, taking advantage of the fact that a `string` is also considered an `IEnumerable<char>`. The `Where` clause will take care of any non-numeric characters that were entered (since you are dealing with user input, after all):

```
var input = "123456789";

var max = input.Where(char.IsDigit).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).Max();
```

`max` will be of type `int`. If you don't care about performing the type conversion, you can eliminate the `Select` statement.

Answer (score 3):

[`char.GetNumericValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k33ktz.aspx) will help you with LINQ `Max`:

```
var max = input.Max(x => char.GetNumericValue(x));
```

Comment: Didn't know about the `char.GetNumericValue` -- very, very cool!

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = "123456789"
var max = int.Parse(input.Max().ToString())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
    if (text.Contains("" + i))
        return i;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var numstring = number.ToString();
var max = Convert.ToInt32(numstring.Max(x => x).ToString());
```

Comment: sigh... people are so trigger happy with the downvote.  It works fine now.